# I am trying to persit a parent entity together with its child entity, parent id is missing on child record

Tags: spring, jpa

I have an entity named service provider entity which has two child entities for payment detials e.g bank. When i save the service provider entity together with child entities in one call the child entity record is saved without the id of the parent entity

In parent entity i have the following relationships :

```
@OneToOne(mappedBy = "serviceProvider", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private Bank bank;
```

In Child entity i have the following relationship

```
@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "service_provider_id", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable=false)
private ServiceProvider serviceProvider;
```

i expect a the service_provider_id field n my child entity Bank to have the id of the parent entity service provider record

Comment: To me it looks relationships are reversed i.e. as per your code samples, `ServiceProvider` looks to be child. So two questions - 1. Which entity owns the relationship 2. Is it uni-directional or bi-directional relationships ?

Answer (score 0):

On bidirectional relation you should set parent on child explicitly before save :

```
parent.setChild(child);
child.setParent(parent);
```

Otherwise the parent id will not be setted.
Bye